# Compiling QGIS source gives LINK errors on Windows

Tags: qgis

I am trying to compile the source of the qgis git : https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS

In order to compile it, I follow the steps of the tutorial here : http://www.qgis.org/api/INSTALL.html (starting on the step 4 "Buildings on Window")

I manage to configure the CMake with all the dependencies and to generate the project. To generate the project I use MSCV10 but I also tried with MSCV express 2008 like in the tutorial.

In the two cases, when I generate the project, I always have the following errors :

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: impossible to open the file '....\core\Release\qgis_core.lib'
>
> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: impossible to open the file '....\analysis\Release\qgis_analysis.lib'

I don't understand why the project tries to open a librairie which is not created yet to compile its code.

How do I solve this problem ?

Apparently, the qgis_core.lib and others must be created during the build (this is why there are theses errors). But the lib is not created because of the errors :

> .\flex_qgsrastercalclexer.cpp(43) : fatal error C1083: imposible to open the hearder file: 'unistd.h' : No such file or directory

Do you know how to add this header to the project ?

I am not very used to MSCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Additionally QGIS also needs the include file unistd.h, which normally
>   doesn't exist on Windows.  It's shipped with Flex/Bison in
>   GnuWin32\include and needs to be copied into the VC\include directory
>   of your Visual C++ installation.

Source:
https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/INSTALL#L603

You need to stick to MSCV (express) 2008 if you don't want to compile all dependencies as well.